# Ruby string split unexpected result

Tags: ruby, split

With this code:

```
"\t\ttest\t\t\t".split(/\t/)
```

I expect the following result:

```
 => ["", "", "test", "", "", ""]
```

But the result is:

```
=> ["", "", "test"]
```

Why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the limit parameter is omitted, trailing null fields are left off the returned array. If it is negative, they are returned:

```
# Supply -1 as the limit parameter
"\t\ttest\t\t\t".split(/\t/, -1)
=> ["", "", "test", "", "", ""]
```

This is detailed in the [`String.split()` documentation.](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-split)

Comment: Cool! thank you! I found that the official document does mention the limit, but I don't know the "null" means the empty string.